# Better way to monitor parent process termination on Linux

Tags: linux

I have a situation. A parent process create a child process, and monitor it and restart the child process if it is terminated. I have no problem for this one.

On the other hand, **when the parent process terminates (crash or normal exit), the child process exits itself immediately**.

On windows, this is easy, start a new thread and wait for its termination

```
HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, dwPid);
if( hProcess ){
        WaitForSingleObject( hProcess, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
}
```

But on Linux, I found it is not easy.

- I tried [NETLINK_CONNECTOR](http://www.databaseskill.com/2731978/) ,  it fails in the reason of "Permission denied", it is impossible for me to elevate the process permission.
- I tried [waitpid](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid), but it does not work for parent process

Now I have to setup a timer and check the parent process every several seconds.

```
if( -1 == kill( pid, 0) && errno == ESRCH ){
     exit(2);
}
```

This is ugly and I can't get the parent-termination-notification immediately.
Please is there other way on Linux to help me to implement this without frequent lookup?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve.  The child dieing with the parent is expected behaviour. What do you want to happen? The child should keep running?

Comment: A crashing parent process shouldn't terminate the child; the child just has its parent changed to pid 1.

Comment: I create my child process with `apr_proc_create` method from Aparch Portable Runtime.  And when the parent process crashes,  the child process still live t here.  What I want is: the child process should die along with parent process